# Open NSViewController from function. Menu Bar App

Tags: swift, macos, function, nsviewcontroller, nsmenuitem

I am trying to open a NSViewController from a function that starts when a NSMenuItem is pressed.

```
func settings (sender: NSStatusBarButton) {

    //open NSViewController here?

}
```

Comment: How is the view controller related to the current class? Are you using storyboard or xib?

Comment: Storyboard @vadian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `NSWindowController` containing the window to be opened has the Storyboard ID `Settings` and the `NSViewController` has the custom class `SettingsController` disable the option `Visible At Launch` of the associated window and use this code

```
var windowController : NSWindowController!
```

---

```
let mainStoryBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
windowController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "Settings") as! NSWindowController
let settingsController = windowController.window!.contentViewController as! SettingsController
// make initial settings before showing the window
windowController.showWindow(self)
```

Comment: The storyboard ID is related to the **`NSWindowController`** the custom class is related to **`NSViewController`** and of course there must be a custom class file `SettingsController.swift` with a subclass of `NSViewController`. I updated the answer.

Comment: (http://imgur.com/a/xQlyO) It now launches but when "show" is clicked in the menu bar the application quits. Also received this in the console (http://imgur.com/a/xQlyO)

Comment: What is the reason for the exception? Set the exception breakpoint, run the app again and after the crash press the continue button in the debug area once. The stack trace and the exception reason is supposed to be printed in the console

Comment: As already mentioned `SettingsController` must be a subclass of `NSViewController` (not `NSObject`)

Comment: I did that and am still receiving SIGBART

Comment: Clear the custom class field of the NSViewController in Interface Builder and reassign `SettingsController`. Then clear the project (⇧⌘K)